# Getting MongoDB error - SyntaxError: Unexpected token?

Tags: mongodb, nosql

I am a Mongo database. There is a collection called `_migrations`. I am trying to insert couple of documents into the collection. But I am getting the following error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ?`. My code is below.

```
db._migrations.insert([
{
  "_id" : "1_create-organization-collection"
},
{
  "_id" : "2_create-dataFilter-collection"
},
{
  "_id" : "3_create-application-collection"
},
{
  "_id" : "4_migrate-datafilters-to-mongo"
},
{
  "_id" : "5_Add-Salesforce-DataFilters"
},
{
  "_id" : "6_biq-repository-data-fiter"
}]);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for all your answers. I have solved the issue. The problem was when I was pasting it in the shell, an extra space character was being inserted after the square brackets. After removing the extra space, the code is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please trying removing underscore("*") in your collection name? I tried with underscore but it did not work for me, but when I tried without underscore("*") same data got inserted. So, please try without underscore in your collection name.

Answer (score 1):

`_id` field value can be inserted after type case with ObjectId. it will work like below -

```
 db._migrations.insert([
   { "_id" : ObjectId("1_create-organization-collection") },  
   { "_id" : ObjectId("2_create-dataFilter-collection") }
 ]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below links for more details about the issue:

[Is there a convention to name collection in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9868323/is-there-a-convention-to-name-collection-in-mongodb)

[Mongo client can't access collections prefixed with an underscore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24309685/mongo-client-cant-access-collections-prefixed-with-an-underscore)

Mongo shell does not support collection name starting with underscore("_")